# If the roots of the cubic equation $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$ are equal, can one then establish a relationship between $a, b, c, d$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, cubics

> If the roots of the cubic equation $$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$$ are equal, can one then establish a relationship between $a, b, c, d$?

Forgive me for any mistake in the wording of the problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the root is triple, then the polynomial is $a(x-r)^3$. This means that
$r=-b/3a$ and you can conclude
$$ c=\frac{b^2}{3a}\quad d=\frac{b^3}{27a^2}.$$

Comment: Don't you think it must have been b³=27a²d , instead of b³= - 27a²d

Comment: @Manthanein. You're right. Answer edited ! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Then note that if the root of the cubic is $\alpha$ with multiplicity $3$, we have: $$(x-\alpha) ^3=0$$ $$\implies \color{red}{1}x^3\color{green}{-3\alpha}x^2\color{blue}{+3\alpha^2}x\color{orange}{-\alpha^3} =0$$
Compare this with the polynomial form you have in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Vieta's formulas](https://brilliant.org/wiki/vietas-formula/) we get relations as 
$$b^3=27a^2d$$
$$b^2=3ac$$
And $$bc=9ad$$